# Not able to call the res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, sinon

I am working on a Node.js application.

This is a code of validate.js file, where I have defined a class Validate and static method validateTicket and at the bottom exported the class.

### validate.js file

```
const request = require("request");
const config = { urlBase: "" };

class Validate {
  static validateTicket = (ticket) => {
    const options = { url: config.urlBase + ticket, json: true, rejectUnauthorized: false };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }

        if (response) {
          resolve(response);
          return;
        }

        reject(null);
      });
    });
  };
}

module.exports = Validate;
```

This is the main utility file where I am importing the validate.js file and there are 3 functions `validateTicketReqs`, `to_json`, and `sendErrorResponse`.

`validateTicketReqs` function do validation on response received from class method.

### util.js file

```
const validate = require('./validate.js');

function validateTicketReqs(req, res, next, flag, num) {

    let payload = req.body;
    let ticket= (payload.ticket) ? payload.ticket: null;
    let error_msg = 'Failed to obtain a successful response '

    validate.validateTicket(ticket).then(
        (resolution) => {
            let json = to_json(resolution); // function will return null value for json
            if (json === null || !('body' in json)) {
                return sendErrorResponse(req, res, 500, 'error');
            }
            ...
            })

function sendErrorResponse(req, res, code, msg) {
    let resBody = {
        msg: msg
    };

    res.status(code);
    res.send(resBody);
}
```

### test_util.js file

```
const validate = require('./validate.js');
describe("Check", () => {


        it("should fail due to error", (done) => {
            let req  = {
            authData: {'user_id': "mock"},
            body: {"num": "mock", "tikcet": "mock"},
            request_id: 'mock'
        }; 
            let res = {send: sinon.spy(), status: sinon.spy()};
            let next = sinon.spy();

            mock_buffer =  {
                toJSON : function() { return {body: {environment: 'mock', status: 'mock'}}},
                statusCode: 500
            }
            const validateTicket= sinon.stub(validate, 'validateTicket')
            validateTicket.resolves(mock_buffer)

            util.valdateTicketReqs(req, res, next, flag, "mock" );

            expect(res.send.calledOnce).to.be.true; ##not getting called
            expect(res.send.firstCall.args[0].statusCode).to.equal(500); ##not getting called


            util.valdateTicketReqs.restore();

            validate.validateTicket.restore();
            done();
        });



    });
```

The problem I am facing is that `(res.send.calledOnce)` value is coming as false. I am expecting that `res.send()` should be called at least once but it is not. Please advise what is the problem here. Let me know if you have a query on the question.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, it might help to try stepping through your program with a debugger. If you are using VS Code as your editor and mocha as your test framework, you can take a look at: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-mocha-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `expect` method is called before the test case finished. The return value of your `validate.validateTicket` method is a promise, it's asynchronous method. You need return it so that test runner will know if the test case is done.

E.g.

`validate.ts`:

```js
const request = require("request");
const config = { urlBase: "" };

class Validate {
  static validateTicket = (ticket) => {
    const options = { url: config.urlBase + ticket, json: true, rejectUnauthorized: false };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }

        if (response) {
          resolve(response);
          return;
        }

        reject(null);
      });
    });
  };
}

module.exports = Validate;
```

`util.ts`:

```js
const validate = require("./validate");

function to_json(data) {
  return null;
}

function sendErrorResponse(req, res, code, msg) {
  const resBody = {
    msg: msg,
  };
  res.status(code);
  res.send(resBody);
}

export function validateTicketReqs(req, res, next, flag, num) {
  const payload = req.body;
  const ticket = payload.ticket ? payload.ticket : null;
  const error_msg = "Failed to obtain a successful response ";

  return validate.validateTicket(ticket).then((resolution) => {
    const json = to_json(resolution);
    if (json === null || !("body" in json)) {
      return sendErrorResponse(req, res, 500, "error");
    }
  });
}
```

`util.spec.ts`:

```js
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";
import * as util from "./util";
const validate = require("./validate");

describe("Check", () => {
  it("should fail due to error", async () => {
    const req = {
      authData: { user_id: "mock" },
      body: { num: "mock", tikcet: "mock" },
      request_id: "mock",
    };
    const res = {
      send: sinon.spy(),
      status: sinon.spy(),
    };
    const next = sinon.spy();
    const flag = "";

    const mock_buffer = {
      toJSON: function() {
        return { body: { environment: "mock", status: "mock" } };
      },
      statusCode: 500,
    };
    const validateTicketStub = sinon.stub(validate, "validateTicket").resolves(mock_buffer);
    await util.validateTicketReqs(req, res, next, flag, "mock");

    expect(res.send.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(res.status.firstCall.args[0]).to.equal(500);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(validateTicketStub);
    validateTicketStub.restore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 Check
    ✓ should fail due to error


  1 passing (19ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |    76.09 |       30 |    63.64 |    75.56 |                   |
 util.spec.ts |    94.12 |      100 |    66.67 |    93.75 |                22 |
 util.ts      |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |              9,14 |
 validate.ts  |     37.5 |        0 |       25 |     37.5 |... 12,15,16,17,20 |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59037819